# Challenging integral evaluation

Tags: probability, integration, combinatorics, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

I computed the following integral and got that
$$\int_S [x_1y_3+x_2(y_2+y_3)+x_3(y_1+y_2)]^n =O\Big(\frac{\log(n)}{n^3}\Big).$$
The integral is over the set $S=\{x_1+x_2+x_3=1, y_1+y_2+y_3=1 | x_i,y_i\geq 0\}$.

I now want evaluate a somewhat different integral, of the form:
$$\int\limits_S
 \sum\limits_k
     \binom{n}{k}\frac1k
      [x_1y_3+x_2(y_2+y_3)+x_3(y_1+y_2)]^{n-k}(x_3y_3)^k$$ over the same domain. So far I have found an upper bound of the form $O\Big(\frac{\log^2(n)}{n^2}\Big)$, which is not good for me. I believe that this upper bound can be improved to $o\Big(\frac1{n^2}\Big)$ but cannot prove this currently.

Is there any good way to evaluate this integral? Any way to prove\disprove that it's $o\Big(\frac1{n^2}\Big)$?

Comment: As a side note, should we have in $S$ only $x_1\ge 0$ or $x_i\ge 0$ for $i=1,2,3$?